# UNIR 2 CONSULTAS MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas en una almaceno la renta de una habitacion que la tabla se llama 'renta' y la otra tabla es la tabla 'habitacion' donde se almacena el estado y su precio.

Quisiera consultar la tabla renta tal como aparece a continuacion: 
select * from renta;

pero agregar una columna mas con el precio de la habitacion que esta en la tabla 
 'habitacion'

select precio from habitacion  ;

cabe destacar que estan unidas por un FK la el numero de habitacion con la habitacion que esta en la tabal renta

Comment: Por favor edita y coloca la estructura de las tablas que mencionas, además de eso edita e indica que gestor de bases de datos usas pues usas tags de 2

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Varias cosas. C# no tiene nada que ver en esta consulta. En si, la base de datos que uses tampoco porque esto es una simple consulta con un join. Lee sobre joins en cualquier pagina de internet y esa es tu solucion. Tambien, para las preguntas de bases de datos, tenes que especificar bien cual es el motor (aca pusiste dos) y la estructura de las tablas.

Answer (score 3):

Para unirlas se utiliza el `INNER JOIN` entonces harias algo como ser

```
SELECT R.Id
       //otras columnas de R
       H.Precio
FROM Renta R
INNER JOIN Habitacion H ON R.HabitacionId = H.Id
```

Al unir por los campos FK puedes usarlo luego en el select

- [MySQL INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT nombre_columna(s)
FROM tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla2
ON tabla1.nombre_columna= tabla2.nombre_columna;
```

[INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT R.*
       H.Precio
FROM Renta R
INNER JOIN Habitacion H ON R.NumHabitacion = H.NumHabitacion
```

Puedes usar:

- INNER JOIN
- o LEFT JOIN

Dependiendo del resultado que quieras.
[image: Tipos de Joins]

Comment: de mucha utilidad gracias